# watch without blank line

Tags: command-line, watch

I want to execute a program periodically and watch when something changes. It sounds like watch would be the right command for that but it prints out annoying empty lines which makes it impossible to see the history. The `-t` switch does not really help here.

What i want:

```
user@machine ~$ #some previous command
user@machine ~$ watch -t date -Is
2020-10-09T12:50:13
2020-10-09T12:50:15
2020-10-09T12:50:17
```

What i get:

```
2020-10-09T12:50:17
```

(all the previous lines are gone).

I know i can use a while loop with a sleep command, but this takes longer to type and has other disadvantages. This loop: `while true; do date -Is ; sleep 2; done` works but i would prefer a simple command. I also read about a trick using tee, like this `watch -t ' date -Is | tee -a ./somefile`, but that is not always a viable solution for me since this only works with a writable filesystem and if it is a tempfs i can not read it after a reboot, which is a problem on a embedded system where i sometimes have no writable file system mounted and i can't read a tempfs after a crash/reboot.

I also tried to filter out empty lines with grep: `watch -t date -Is | grep -v '^$'` but then i have no output.

Comment: Don't the previous lines appear as soon as you exit `watch`?

Comment: `watch` uses ncurses-type terminal codes to rewrite the outputs. The output characters are disjoint, TERM-dependent, not arranged in lines, and not stored anywhere.

Comment: `watch` also breaks your terminal settings occasionally, requiring a `reset`.

Answer (score 2):

A bit convoluted, but you could do:

```
yes 'date -Is' | pv -qlL1 | sh
```

(also has the advantage to run the command every second, instead of every 2 seconds plus however  long it takes to run it)

`1` above is the rate in number of lines per second and can only be an integer number. So 1 per second is the slowest you can get. You could drop the `-l` though in which case, the rate would be in number of *bytes* per second. So at 9 bytes per line, that'd be one command every 9 seconds.

Comment: Interesting side-effect: `yes` instantly fills the pipe, so if you kill `yes` the pipeline continues for a couple of hours (64KB of commands). Now I need to find a use for that.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant why is it that interesting? What were you expecting?

Comment: @Căcărău I'm not familiar with pv: intuitively, I expected the throttling to be be pre-emptive. Also, ulimit says my pipe size is 4KB, but experiment says 64KB.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant, you may be refering to `bash`'s `ulimit -p`. I believe on Linux it reports `PIPE_BUF` which is the maximum amount of data that `write()`s is guaranteed to write atomically (not much to do with the size of pipes). On Linux, the default size of pipes is 64KiB (up from 4KiB since 2.6.11), though can be changed dynamically on a per-pipe basis.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant how could `pv` preempt the process writing to the other end of the pipe?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas With all due respect, I don't think that this is useful at all. This will keep printing the output of the command again and again, even if it hasn't changed. Nothing like "watch" at all. It's just a weird variant of `(while sleep 1; do date -Is & done)`.

Comment: @Căcărău `pv` can't do that. In a weak moment, I was expecting the gods of Linux to shelter me.

Comment: @Căcărău It is not now clear exactly what the requirement is, being as the `date` in the question was only a placeholder for some unknown command. The part about "watch outputs blank lines" was wrong: watch clears the whole screen intentionally, and it highlights new and changed characters. If the unknown command produces multi-line output, and the requirement is to show previous and new output, that probably deserves spacing and timestamping and highlighting differences. Might as well save each successive output in a file and diff it with its predecessor.

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -e '$t=shift; while(1){print $o=$n if ($n=qx(@ARGV)) ne $o; sleep $t}' 1 date -Is
2020-10-07T06:49:07+03:00
2020-10-07T06:49:08+03:00
2020-10-07T06:49:09+03:00
2020-10-07T06:49:10+03:00
```

An improved version which does fractional delays and correctly handles spaces and special characters in the command & args:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use Time::HiRes qw(sleep);
die "usage: $0 delay cmd [args ...]\n" if @ARGV < 2;
sub slurpcmd {
   open my $h, '-|', @_ or die "open $_[0]|: $!";
   local $/ unless wantarray;
   <$h>
}
my $t = shift; my ($o, $n);
while(1){print $o=$n if ($n=slurpcmd @ARGV) ne $o; sleep $t}
```

Adding options to format the output of the command (nicely separate it if multiline, etc) is left as exercise to the reader ;-)